# assigning apex value in the html input text & rendering as pdf

Tags: visualforce, html

I'm using html `<input>` tag for creating a text box HTML page, I need to value of the apex field in that box. 
I've written the following line for it.

```
<input style="border:1px solid #007ACC;width:23px;height:25px;" disabled="true" type="text" name="name" value="{!CDOB_Day1}"/>
```

I can see the value in the vf page but when I do `renderAs="pdf"` the value in not appearing
Please Help
[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Hi Tabrez, values in input tags are not rendered in pdf. You can make
>   one more tag to show data and render it only when renderAs="pdf". Here
>   is a sample code:

```
/*****page*****/
<apex:page standardController="OBJECTNAME" extensions="CLASSNAME" renderAs="{!classVariable}">

<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!classVariable != "pdf"}">
    <input style="border:1px solid #007ACC;width:23px;height:25px;" disabled="true" type="text" name="name" value="{!CDOB_Day1}"/>
</apex:outputPanel>
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!classVariable == "pdf"}">
    <p style="border:1px solid #007ACC;width:23px;height:25px;">{!CDOB_Day1}</p>
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>
```

Its just a sample code design. You can modify it as per your requirement. Hope this may help.